# Add class to an element in Angular 4

Tags: css, angular

I was trying to create an image gallery with Angular 4.The logic behind this is to add a Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) class to the selected image that will show a red border on the selected (clicked) image. This is the CSS stylesheet for an image gallery.

I want to show a red selection square on the image I have clicked. `this-is-a-class` should be added to the selected image.

```css
#container{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:auto;
}

ul li{
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-left:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline;
}

ul li img{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

#select{
  border:2px solid violet;
}

.this-is-a-class{
  border: 10px solid red !important;
}
```

following is the template code

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><img class="this-is-a-class" id="1" src="../../assets/images/1.jpg" (click)="addClass(id=1)"/></li>
    <li><img id="select" src="../../assets/images/2.png" (click)="addClass(id=2)"/></li>
    <li><img id="3" src="../../assets/images/3.jpg" (click)="addClass(id=3)"/></li>
    <li><img id="4" src="../../assets/images/4.png" (click)="addClass(id=4)"/></li>
    <li><img id="5" src="../../assets/images/5.jpg" (click)="addClass(id=5)"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>You Clicked on: {{id}}</h1>
</div>
```

The component code is as follows

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  constructor() {
    console.log("Constructor working..")

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit works..');
  }

  //function to add the class to selected image to show the border.
  addClass(id) {
    this.id = id;
    //id = this.id? 'selectedImg' : 'null';
  }
}
```

Comment: is the css working fine if you assign it to li manually ?

Comment: It is working fine.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: How would you do this if you were using ngFor and don't have specific ids for each element?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use `[ngClass]` and conditionally apply class based on the `id`.

**In your HTML file**:

```html
<li>
    <img [ngClass]="{'this-is-a-class': id === 1 }" id="1"  
         src="../../assets/images/1.jpg" (click)="addClass(id=1)"/>
</li>
<li>
    <img [ngClass]="{'this-is-a-class': id === 2 }" id="2"  
         src="../../assets/images/2.png" (click)="addClass(id=2)"/>
</li>
```

**In your TypeScript file:**

```ts
addClass(id: any) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: i want to add the class dynamically to the element when i click on it.

Comment: and that why im using ngClass

Comment: Can we also remove the class we added?

Comment: How would you do this if you were using ngFor and don't have specific ids for each element?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PbOEWQS369yMVfrBdIXS?p=preview) showing how you can use it with the `ngClass` directive.

I'm demonstrating with `div`s instead of `img`s though.

Template:

```
<ul>
      <li><div [ngClass]="{'this-is-a-class': selectedIndex == 1}" (click)="setSelected(1)"> </div></li>
      <li><div [ngClass]="{'this-is-a-class': selectedIndex == 2}" (click)="setSelected(2)"> </div></li>
      <li><div [ngClass]="{'this-is-a-class': selectedIndex == 3}" (click)="setSelected(3)"> </div></li>
</ul>
```

TS:

```
export class App {
  selectedIndex = -1;

  setSelected(id: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = id;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to set only one specific class, you might write a TypeScript function returning a boolean to determine when the class should be appended.

**TypeScript**

```
function hideThumbnail():boolean{
    if (/* Your criteria here */)
        return true;
}
```

**CSS**:

```
.request-card-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<ion-note [class.request-card-hidden]="hideThumbnail()"></ion-note>
```

Comment: This is the least disruptive option (tho not always feasible.)  Even as of Angular 8, you can get into situations where `ngClass` results will override what someone else has done, rather than giving you a pure union.  I think typically when one or more directives use `ngClass` in addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that each div will have its own toggle and don't want clicks to affect other divs, do this:

Here's what I did to solve this...

```
<div [ngClass]="{'teaser': !teaser_1 }" (click)="teaser_1=!teaser_1">
...content...
</div>

<div [ngClass]="{'teaser': !teaser_2 }" (click)="teaser_2=!teaser_2">
...content...
</div>

<div [ngClass]="{'teaser': !teaser_3 }" (click)="teaser_3=!teaser_3">
...content...
</div>
```

it requires custom numbering which sucks, but it works.

Answer (score -5):

you can try this without any java script you can do that just by using CSS

```
img:active,
img:focus,
img:hover{ 
border: 10px solid red !important
}
```

of if your case is to add any other css class by clicking you can use query selector like

```
<img id="image1" ng-click="changeClass(id)" >
<img id="image2" ng-click="changeClass(id)" >
<img id="image3" ng-click="changeClass(id)" >
<img id="image3" ng-click="changeClass(id)" >
```

in controller first search for any image with red border and remove it then by passing the image id add the border class to that image

```
$scope.changeClass = function(id){
angular.element(document.querySelector('.some-class').removeClass('.some-class');
angular.element(document.querySelector(id)).addClass('.some-class');
}
```

Comment: angular 4 - $scope?

Comment: oops! i thought angularjs anyhow u can use the logic

Comment: check out ngClass as it's an infinitely better answer than this. also you shouldnt use !important by default

Comment: This is angular.js, not angular