# Angular add class dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular

Is there a way to add a class from the .ts file, using Angular solutions

```
<div [class.extra-sparkle]="isDelightful == true">
```

I want to do the above but from the side of the .ts file. The less code the better.

```
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen('Global')"       [class.selected]="CurrentPage == 'Global'">Global</button>
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen('Maintenance')"  [class.selected]="CurrentPage == 'Maintenance'">Maintenance</button>
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen('Settings')"     [class.selected]="CurrentPage == 'Settings'">Settings</button>
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen('Profile')"      [class.selected]="CurrentPage == 'Profile'">Profile</button>
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen('Transactions')" [class.selected]="CurrentPage == 'Transactions'">Transactions</button>
```

I would like to just add something like this into the ChangeScreen function:

```
ChangeScreen(page) {
    page.addClass = page;
}
```

Then I can remove all of those lines: `[class.selected]="CurrentPage == '...'"`

Comment: you can add dynamic class using directive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to an element in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816271/add-class-to-an-element-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 58):

You can use `ngClass` directive:

```
<div id="mydiv" [ngClass]="{'myCSSclass' : condition}"></div>
```

Simple as that! myDiv will have the class `myCSSclass` only when the `condition` evaluates to `true`. This condition can be set in your typescript file or in the template.

Answer (score 18):

**Use `Renderer`**

See here:https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer

and here:https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer#setElementClass

```
import { Renderer } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private render:Renderer) { }

ChangeScreen(event:any) {
 this.renderer.setElementClass(event.target,"selected",true);
}
```

In html:

```
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen()">Global</button>
```

**Or `Render2`:**

See here:https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

and here:https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#addClass

```
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private render:Renderer2) { }

ChangeScreen(event:any) {
 this.renderer.addClass(event.target,"selected");
}
```

In html:

```
<button class="general" (click)="ChangeScreen($event)">Global</button>
```

Comment: The class I am adding is `.selected`, not the page names

Comment: But if you now have 10 buttons with `[ngClass]="page"` then they will all get the `.selected` applied. I only want one to be selected at a time

Comment: I think better use Render2

Comment: We are getting there :) ! Haha. The problem now is that you need to remove the `.selected` from all the previous ones. Because this will add the `.selected` class nicely, but it never removes previous ones

Comment: of course and you have removeclass function (and I an woman:) )

Comment: Haha my bad, I removed the "man" for you :) Would you mind adding the remove function to your example as well please? Then the answer is more complete

Comment: use `this.renderer.removeClass('button', 'selected');` then add class to selected

Comment: I am getting an error `Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`

Comment: constructor(private render:Renderer2) { } <- Here used RENDER
this.renderer.setElementClass(event.target,"selected",true); <- Here RENDERER

For people getting the same Error

Answer (score 4):

While the solution with the Renderer works, I am proposing you create a data structure for your buttons

```
buttons: Array<{label: string}> = [
    {
      label: 'Global'
    },
    {
      label: 'Maintenance'
    },
    {
      label: 'Settings'
    },
    {
      label: 'Profile'
    },
    {
      label: 'Transactions'
    }
  ]
```

This can easily be iterated through using [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

```
<button 
  *ngFor="let button of buttons" 
  class="general" 
  (click)="ChangeScreen(button.label)" 
  [class.selected]="CurrentPage == button.label">
  {{ button.label }}
</button>
```

And only thing your `ChangeScreen` method would need is... the thing its already doing, setting the current page!

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buttons-classes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for an example of how this plays out.

Comment: I don't feel like this really solves the 'Angular add class dynamically' problem, but this is an awesome solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Add a class in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#binding-to-a-single-css-class) **programmatically** with `class`

```
[class]="obj.param.name"
```