# How to add animation effect on bubbles in datamaps angular 8?

Tags: angular, animation, datamaps

I am looking to add animation effect on the bubbles in the svg map using the datamaps in angular 8. the bubbles are displayed correctly but the animation is not working. This is what I have tried so far

```
.bubbles circle.datamaps-bubble  {
  -webkit-animation: ripple 0.7s linear infinite;
      animation: ripple 0.7s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
 }
 100% {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
 }
}
@keyframes ripple {
 0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3);
 }
 100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 3em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 5em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0.3), 0 0 0 8em rgba(101, 255, 120, 0);
 }
}
```

Comment: If this is what you've tried, i see no point in mentioning angular here. This is just css.

Comment: I tried using angular as well. but to no avail so I am trying to use in css only. I mentioned angular because I am using datamaps in angular 8

Comment: That's irrelevant, it is not part of angular. I'm assuming you are using https://datamaps.github.io/

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#Events essentially, just add your ripple effects' css-class to your bubble programmatically.

Comment: yes I am using this and the following github code https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps

Comment: Since the elements are already drawn onto the screen - use Angular Renderer. Look here for an example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51187386/2902996

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using a plugin fading bubbles

```
this.worldMap.addPlugin('fadingBubbles', fadingBubbles);

_this = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        drawBubbles(_this);
     }, 2000); 
    drawBubbles(this);
    _drawDOT(this);
    function drawBubbles(that){
        that.worldMap.fadingBubbles(that.mapBubbles, {  });

    }
```