# Remove and add class dynamically triggering change detection in between (Angular 2+)

Tags: css, angular, css-animations, angular12

In short, I am trying to trigger a change detection loop between `renderer.removeStyle` and `renderer.addStyle`.
The style I am adding is an css animation. When it's removed and added in the same change detection loop Angular won't detect that something changed (for the same animation name).

#### More Details

Let's say I have a button event `(click)="addAnimation('animation1')"` that should add existing animation and add the new animation named `animation1, animation2 ...`.
Of course the following code won't work:

```js
  addAnimation(animationName: string): void {
    this.renderer.removeStyle(this.animate.nativeElement, 'animation');
    // setTimeout(() => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.animate.nativeElement, 'animation', animationName)
    // }, 0);
  }
```

since removing and adding a style under angular nose won't trigger any change.

One possible solution is adding a timeout (like the commented code above, but it has side effects that I am not interested in, and also the code is a little wired.

I was hoping to solve it by adding something like `this.appRef.tick();` in between to force angular create another change detection loop.

That doesn't work, what am I missing? any suggestions how to do that correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: do you have to use it to multiple elements and each element add different classes?

Comment: can you clarify the question? I am not sure I understand it.

Comment: i have my answer here it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187256/angular-add-class-dynamically/51187386#51187386

Comment: @לבנימלכה please read the question. It's not about using renderer, it's about change detection.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way.

```
isClick=false;
onClick(){
    isClick=true;
}

<div [ngClass]="{'yourCSSClass': isClick}">
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. That's a very limited solution, it will require a lot of maintenance to add new classes. I am looking for a dynamic solution to inject animations on the fly. I will update my question to clarify that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution might be use of the css animation lifecycle events such as the `animationend`, all supported by Angular V5 and up.

Within your checkAnimateChange() function you can then flip the appropriate flag of the new animation or no additional animation, creating an animation sequence based on rules and using `[ngClass]` directive.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'animate1': animate1Flag, 'animate2':animate2Flag ... }" (animationend)="checkAnimateChange()">
```